# How to open a MySQL file?

Tags: php, mysql

I have been sent a MySQL file from a 3rd party company but i do not know how to open it?  The file name is **edir_db_dump_07052013** so it appears to be some kind of data dump file i guess!?

I do not have MySQL or knowledge of PHP which other related posts seem to mention.

Does anyone know how i can open the file to access the contents?  ideally i would like to transfer the contents to Excel somehow but first i need to get at the data within it?

Any help for a newbie on this much appreciated.

edit - i have installed the MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver already - if that's important at all

Comment: If you open it in a simple text editor, what do you see?

Comment: I can see a DB creation script

Comment: @knookie It's basically SQL that will recreate the database :)

Comment: You can LOAD it, import it, or just copy and paste it into a query prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds (and is named like) a mysql dump from PHPMyAdmin. If you install something like WAMP it will come with PHPMyAdmin in the installer.

You can simply then import directly through the PHPMyAdmin app and you will have the database nice and ready to use.

Here is a link to a [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgIJf0Ij3DI) that shows you how to import a database.

Comment: wow thanks for the fast answer - i will give that a go and post back

Comment: @knookie I edited to give you a link to follow to install it.

Comment: excellent - thank you - unfortunately that video does not appear to be available anymore :(

Comment: @knookie The link is working perfectly well for me here?

Comment: Yes it is working for me too now - go figure - thank you

Comment: Thank for your help - the girl here who asked me to extract the data has now realised she can import it directly from the 3rd party client into Excel which she has now done.  Great answers though.

Comment: @knookie PHPMyAdmin also imports CSVs and the like if you have the table structure in place already :)